# Javascript adds class to elements but does not work out what class it should be for each

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

**Edit**

I have 2 coupons showing, they both have the .new-coupon when in fact one should say .new-coupon and one should say .old-coupon. It seems to apply the same class for every element on the page with that class instead of calculating which class it should be for each element.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Set the date we're counting down to
  var deadlineYear = $("#clockdiv .year").attr("rel");
  var deadlineMonth = $("#clockdiv .month").attr("rel");
  var deadlineDay = $("#clockdiv .days").attr("rel");
  var deadlineHour = $("#clockdiv .hours").attr("rel");
  var deadlineMinute = $("#clockdiv .minutes").attr("rel");
  var deadlineSecond = $("#clockdiv .seconds").attr("rel");
  var couponExpired = $("#clockdiv").attr("rel");

  var countDownDate = new Date(deadlineYear + "/" + deadlineMonth + "/" + deadlineDay + " " + deadlineHour + ":" + deadlineMinute + ":" + deadlineSecond).getTime();

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {

// Get todays date and time
var now = new Date().getTime();

// Find the distance between now and the count down date
var distance = countDownDate - now;

// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

// Output the result in an element with id="demo"

document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days;
document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours;
document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML= seconds;

// If the count down is over, write some text 
if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("clockdiv").innerHTML = "<p>" + couponExpired + "</p>";
}

var startDate = $("#clockdiv .start").attr("rel"); //2018/09/28 17:00:00

  var startDateNew = new Date(startDate);
  var newOldDate = new Date(startDateNew.setDate(startDateNew.getDate() + 7));
  var nowDateNew = new Date(now);

  if (days <= 7) {
      $('.couponDiv').addClass("old-coupon");
  } else if ((nowDateNew.getTime() - newOldDate.getTime()) < 0) {
      $('.couponDiv').addClass("new-coupon");
  }    
  }, 1000);
});
```

**Edit: Not duplicate.**

Please do not mark this as duplicate without linking me to a resource which does explain how to fix my problems, you all state issues yet no one states a method to fix them. Please assist as the marked duplicate post only details that ID's must be unique not how to solve my issue.

Comment: It would be great if you add Html code as well!

Comment: an `ID` should be **unique** in the page.

Comment: `$('#couponDiv')`, the # indicates an id, you may only have one element with a particular id, so it won't execute for other elements, as ths has said.

Comment: appreciate these replies, changed it to classes and have a new issues where it uses the outcome of the if statement for all the divs instead of recalculating for each. Not sure why it's flagged as a duplicate can you all request a reopen.

Comment: @DanielVickers, you should make a new question as the comments and marking now longer fit.  You made changes and now have a *new* question.  Currently you don't seem to be evaluating each coupon individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your code is essentially only applying your new class to the .couponDiv a singular time. Your if statement is being called once and then applying the new class, either old-coupon or new-coupon, accordingly. To check individually for the .couponDiv's against your parameters you need to wrap them in a loop. Something along the lines of this:

```
$('.couponDiv').each(function() {
  if(days <= 7) {
     $(this).addClass('old-coupon')
  } else if ((nowDateNew.getTime() - newOldDate.getTime()) < 0) {
     $(this).addClass('new-coupon')
  }
})
```

As to the rest of the code. It seems that you're only checking the #clockdiv against the system date which is another reason why they are all being given the same class since all of the .couponDiv's are being used with the same value. There is no other values being checked. If you have other data to pull in from the .couponDiv's to check against in the if statement that will also provide you with the desired outcome.

So in summary. Pull in div data to check in the if statement. And put your .couponDiv's in a loop to check each individually. Hope this helps get you thinking about ways to solve your issue.

Comment: This works for adding the class, i have a new question open including my HTML in order to get assistance with looping for the new dates. Feel free to check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561225/javascript-adds-same-class-to-divs-without-calculating-for-each-div?noredirect=1#comment92062460_52561225