# Javascript Adds Same Class To Divs Without Calculating For Each Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have 2 coupons showing, they both have the .new-coupon when in fact one should say .new-coupon and one should say .old-coupon. It seems to apply the same class for every element on the page with that class instead of calculating which class it should be for each element.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Set the date we're counting down to
  var deadlineYear = $("#clockdiv .year").attr("rel");
  var deadlineMonth = $("#clockdiv .month").attr("rel");
  var deadlineDay = $("#clockdiv .days").attr("rel");
  var deadlineHour = $("#clockdiv .hours").attr("rel");
  var deadlineMinute = $("#clockdiv .minutes").attr("rel");
  var deadlineSecond = $("#clockdiv .seconds").attr("rel");
  var couponExpired = $("#clockdiv").attr("rel");

  var countDownDate = new Date(deadlineYear + "/" + deadlineMonth + "/" + deadlineDay + " " + deadlineHour + ":" + deadlineMinute + ":" + deadlineSecond).getTime();

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {

// Get todays date and time
var now = new Date().getTime();

// Find the distance between now and the count down date
var distance = countDownDate - now;

// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

// Output the result in an element with id="demo"

document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days;
document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours;
document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML= seconds;

// If the count down is over, write some text 
if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("clockdiv").innerHTML = "<p>" + couponExpired + "</p>";
}

var startDate = $("#clockdiv .start").attr("rel"); //2018/09/28 17:00:00

  var startDateNew = new Date(startDate);
  var newOldDate = new Date(startDateNew.setDate(startDateNew.getDate() + 7));
  var nowDateNew = new Date(now);

  if (days <= 7) {
      $('.couponDiv').addClass("old-coupon");
  } else if ((nowDateNew.getTime() - newOldDate.getTime()) < 0) {
      $('.couponDiv').addClass("new-coupon");
  }    
  }, 1000);
});
```

HTML used for variables:

```
<div id="clockdiv" rel="'.$expired.'">
<span class="start" rel="'.$start.'"></span>
<span class="year" rel="'.$year.'"></span>
<span class="month" rel="'.$month.'"></span>
<div><span id="days" class="days" rel="'.$day.'"></span><div class="smalltext">Days</div></div>
<div><span id="hours" class="hours" rel="'.$hour.'"></span><div class="smalltext">Hours</div></div>
<div><span id="minutes" class="minutes" rel="'.$minute.'"></span><div class="smalltext">Minutes</div></div>
<div><span id="seconds" class="seconds" rel="'.$second.'"></span><div class="smalltext">Seconds</div></div>
</div>
```

HTML used for displaying the coupons on the offers page:

```
<li>
                    <?php
                    $year = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', get_field('offer_voucher_deadline'))->format('Y');
                    $month = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', get_field('offer_voucher_deadline'))->format('m');
                    $day = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', get_field('offer_voucher_deadline'))->format('d');
                    $hour = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', get_field('offer_voucher_deadline'))->format('H');
                    $minute = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', get_field('offer_voucher_deadline'))->format('i');
                    $second = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', get_field('offer_voucher_deadline'))->format('s');

                    $humanDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', get_field('offer_voucher_deadline'))->format('D jS M Y');
                    $expiredText = get_field('offer_voucher_expired');
                    ?>
                <div style="display:none;">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[gw-countdown expired="'.$expiredText.'" year="'.$year.'" month="'.$month.'" day="'.$day.'" hour="'.$hour.'" minute="'.$minute.'" second="'.$second.'" start="'.get_field('offer_voucher_start').'"]');?>
                </div>
                <div id="couponDiv" class="couponDiv">
                    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
                    <div class="couponDetails">
                        <div class="couponView">
                            <?php $offer = get_field('offer_single_label', 'options'); $offerC = ucwords($offer);?>
                            <a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="See Offer Details">See <?php echo $offerC;?> Details</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="couponValid">
                            <p class="bold">Valid Until:</p>
                            <p class="couponDate"><?php echo $humanDate;?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>
```

**Edit**

I understand completely where the issue lies, and have updated the code to the following:

```
$('.couponDiv').each(function() {

    var startDate = $("#clockdiv .start").attr("rel"); //2018/09/28 17:00:00
    var startDateNew = new Date(startDate);
    var newOldDate = new Date(startDateNew.setDate(startDateNew.getDate() + 7));
    var nowDateNew = new Date(now);


    if (days <= 7) {
        $(this).addClass("old-coupon");
    } else if ((nowDateNew.getTime() - newOldDate.getTime()) < 0) {
        $(this).addClass("new-coupon");
    }
  });
```

However, I do not know how to make:

```
var startDate = $("#clockdiv .start").attr("rel");
```

Apply to $this so its $this #clockdiv .start because then it will work I believe...

**Edit**

I have altered a line of code to read:

```
var startDate = $(this).find("#clockdiv .start").attr("rel");
```

This now only adds the class to the first offer and not the 2nd offer, I then tried repeating the:

$(this).find()

Around the initial variables and then moved the:

```
$('.couponDiv').each(function() {
```

To the top below the document ready function however, this stopped any class being added.

Comment: Is there something in each `.coupon` that you can use to evaluate new or old?  Right now you seem to be using the same dates/times for the calculation for all `coupon`.  HTML would be helpful to assist.

Comment: @Steve0 I have added all relevant HTML/PHP

Comment: You're only doing a date calculation one time for the entire application, rather than redoing the calculation with different dates for each coupon. Also you have both id="couponDiv" and class="couponDiv" this is bad, two elements cannot have the same id

Comment: @Our_Benefactors I know this, that's why I am asking how to run it more than once for each coupon?

Comment: @DanielVickers you need to use jQuery.each()

Comment: I tried this apparently i did not use it correctly, feel free to answer the question

Comment: @DanielVickers I would recommend you read some more tutorials on how jQuery.each() works. If you complete them, I am confident you'll have an 'aha!' moment for how your mental model differs from the API spec https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-each-function-examples/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180961/discussion-between-our-benefactors-and-daniel-vickers).

Comment: Does `#clockdiv` appear multiple times? Is that from the shortcode function? Are you able to modify it? The selector.

Comment: It would be used multiple times, I have tried it as a class however and it still doesn't work. But yes I am able to modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reconstructing and work with $this I was able to get this working:

```
$('.couponWrap .coupons li').each(function() {
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var deadlineYear = $(this).find("div .clockdiv .year").attr("rel");
    var deadlineMonth = $(this).find("div .clockdiv .month").attr("rel");
    var deadlineDay = $(this).find("div .clockdiv .days").attr("rel");
    var deadlineHour = $(this).find("div .clockdiv .hours").attr("rel");
    var deadlineMinute = $(this).find("div .clockdiv .minutes").attr("rel");
    var deadlineSecond = $(this).find("div .clockdiv .seconds").attr("rel");
    var couponExpired = $(this).find("div .clockdiv").attr("rel");

    var countDownDate = new Date(deadlineYear + "/" + deadlineMonth + "/" + deadlineDay + " " + deadlineHour + ":" + deadlineMinute + ":" + deadlineSecond).getTime();
    var startDate = new Date($(this).find("div .clockdiv .start").attr("rel"));

    var self = $(this);

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

      // Get todays date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now and the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      // Output the result in an element with id="demo"

      document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days;
      document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours;
      document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
      document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML= seconds;

      // If the count down is over, write some text 
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("clockdiv").innerHTML = "<p>" + couponExpired + "</p>";
      }

      //Works but only for 1st start date
      //var testDate = $("div .clockdiv .start").attr("rel"); //2018/09/28 17:00:00

      var startDateNew = new Date(startDate);
      var startDateNewer = new Date(startDate);
      var newOldDate = new Date(startDateNewer.setDate(startDateNew.getDate() + 7));

      //alert(startDate + ", " +  startDateNew + ", " + startDateNewer + ", " + newOldDate);

      //This works fine
      var nowDateNew = new Date().getTime();

      //alert(nowDateNew - newOldDate.getTime());

      if (days <= 7) {
        self.find('div.couponDiv').addClass("old-coupon");
      } else if ((nowDateNew - newOldDate.getTime()) < 0) {
        self.find('div.couponDiv').addClass("new-coupon");
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (days <= 7) {
   $('.couponDiv').addClass("old-coupon");
} else if ((nowDateNew.getTime() - newOldDate.getTime()) < 0) {
   $('.couponDiv').addClass("new-coupon");
}
```

In your codes above, you had selected all of `.couponDiv` to add class `old-coupon` and once again you select all of `.couponDiv` to add class `new-coupon`. The conditions have no meaning here because with any matching you still add class for all elements.

You must separate which elements are belong to "old" and with elements are belong to "new". Then add the respectively class name.

Comment: I appreciate the pointer but I know the issue just not know how to resolve it and as mentioned in the bounty: "I am looking for a solution not a pointer. Much appreciated."

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
var startDate = $(this).find("#clockdiv .start").attr("rel"); //2018/09/28 17:00:00
```

Comment: I added this and then it only added the class to the first offer and not the 2nd offer, I then tried adding the .each() after the first line and then adding $this().find... for all the variables and it stopped adding all the classes.

Comment: Actually testing it, this half works it solves that problem but now $days is the same for each coupon so I need everything to calculate for .each() but it's not working when i move the function above the code.